# Combining statements, while referring to earlier statement in pipeline

Tags: powershell

While answering a question here, I used the following code

```
$DataFile = Get-Item  'c:\temp\2015-01.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $DataFile -Delimiter ';' | 
    Measure-Object -Property 'E_TodayKwh' -Sum  | 
    Select-Object @{label="NewName";expression={$DataFile.BaseName + '_' + $_.Sum + $DataFile.Extension}} |
    Rename-Item $DataFile
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a way to combine the first and second statement, while still being able to reference e.g. `$DataFile.BaseName` in the second statement's pipeline. I looked at `-PipelineVariable`, but that doesn't seem applicable here (I think?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to approach combining these particular statements is to *invert them*. That is, instead of `Import-Csv` being the "pipeline driver", the operation should be driven by the file input, and `Import-Csv` then becomes a contingent operation you can nest in your renaming operation:

```
Get-Item 'c:\temp\2015-01.csv' |Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}_{1}.{2}' -f $_.BaseName,($_ |Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' |Measure-Object -Sum E_TodayKwh).Sum,$_.Extension}
```

This way, the operation is also easily adapted to multiple files in the future:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Recurse |Rename-Item ...
```